Flutter Android 14 get WiFi SSID
I try get WiFi SSID on my Android device using library:
https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus
Of course I add to AndroidManifest.xml lines:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

With sample code:
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

// Sets a platform override for desktop to avoid exceptions. See
// https://flutter.dev/desktop#target-platform-override for more info.
void _enablePlatformOverrideForDesktop() {
  if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux)) {
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
  }
}

void main() {
  _enablePlatformOverrideForDesktop();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0x9f4376f8),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, this.title});

  final String? title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _connectionStatus = 'Unknown';
  final NetworkInfo _networkInfo = NetworkInfo();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initNetworkInfo();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('NetworkInfoPlus example'),
        elevation: 4,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Network info',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          Text(_connectionStatus),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _initNetworkInfo() async {
    String? wifiName,
        wifiBSSID,
        wifiIPv4,
        wifiIPv6,
        wifiGatewayIP,
        wifiBroadcast,
        wifiSubmask;

    try {
      if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS)) {
        // Request permissions as recommended by the plugin documentation:
        // https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/network_info_plus/network_info_plus
        if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request().isGranted) {
          wifiName = await _networkInfo.getWifiName();
        } else {
          wifiName = 'Unauthorized to get Wifi Name';
        }
      } else {
        wifiName = await _networkInfo.getWifiName();
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      developer.log('Failed to get Wifi Name', error: e);
      wifiName = 'Failed to get Wifi Name';
    }

    try {
      if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS)) {
        // Request permissions as recommended by the plugin documentation:
        // https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/network_info_plus/network_info_plus
        if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request().isGranted) {
          wifiBSSID = await _networkInfo.getWifiBSSID();
        } else {
          wifiBSSID = 'Unauthorized to get Wifi BSSID';
        }
      } else {
        wifiName = await _networkInfo.getWifiName();
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      developer.log('Failed to get Wifi BSSID', error: e);
      wifiBSSID = 'Failed to get Wifi BSSID';
    }

    try {
      wifiIPv4 = await _networkInfo.getWifiIP();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      developer.log('Failed to get Wifi IPv4', error: e);
      wifiIPv4 = 'Failed to get Wifi IPv4';
    }

    try {
      wifiIPv6 = await _networkInfo.getWifiIPv6();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      developer.log('Failed to get Wifi IPv6', error: e);
      wifiIPv6 = 'Failed to get Wifi IPv6';
    }

    try {
      wifiSubmask = await _networkInfo.getWifiSubmask();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      developer.log('Failed to get Wifi submask address', error: e);
      wifiSubmask = 'Failed to get Wifi submask address';
    }

    try {
      wifiBroadcast = await _networkInfo.getWifiBroadcast();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      developer.log('Failed to get Wifi broadcast', error: e);
      wifiBroadcast = 'Failed to get Wifi broadcast';
    }

    try {
      wifiGatewayIP = await _networkInfo.getWifiGatewayIP();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      developer.log('Failed to get Wifi gateway address', error: e);
      wifiGatewayIP = 'Failed to get Wifi gateway address';
    }

    setState(() {
      _connectionStatus = 'Wifi Name: $wifiName\n'
          'Wifi BSSID: $wifiBSSID\n'
          'Wifi IPv4: $wifiIPv4\n'
          'Wifi IPv6: $wifiIPv6\n'
          'Wifi Broadcast: $wifiBroadcast\n'
          'Wifi Gateway: $wifiGatewayIP\n'
          'Wifi Submask: $wifiSubmask\n';
    });
  }
}

I receive all info, but without SSID:

Moreover I try other libraries like:

https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus
https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot
https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus/example

And I can receive a lot of information about WiFi, but no one library can provide SSID... Why?

Looks like you are missing permission as per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo#getSSID()
You can see that the BSSID is indeed 02:00:00:00:00:00

what is name of this permission? I try <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/> but unfortunately it is not correct answer :/

Fine location permission is required. It is dangerous level permission. I am not sure how permission_handler plugin handles it.
